# embedded HTML form is discarded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

It seems Chrome ignores forms that are embedded inside another form.

See this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/NbUeQ/1/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div id="dialog">
        <form id="theForm">
            <label>abc</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
alert($('#theForm').length);
```

Note 'theForm' is not found.

Is the only solution to not have embedded forms?

Comment: What is the meaning of embedding forms? AFAIK, the form is the envelope that groups all the input controls sent together. Why do you need nested forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The only solutions is not to embedded forms as this is not valid HTML.

See the W3C XHTML spec's Element Prohibitions section at http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions